# Is it possible to get the selection order of items from a dropdown box generated using collection_select?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms

**Question**: Is it possible to get the selection order of items from a dropdown box generated using collection_select?

I am doing the following in a simple form:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, {}, html_options = {:multiple => true} ) %>
```

With this I can get an array of selected Categories, however they are arranged in a top-down order (as they appear in the list).

For example, say I have the following categories:

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue
4. Orange

If I pick Green, Orange, Red I would like to get a return array of [2, 4, 1] but I get [1, 2, 4] instead.

I found this post that mentions it's a HTML standard thing for them to be ordered this way. Is there a way around this?

[Order of selection in html select multiple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10446796/order-of-selection-in-html-select-multiple)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, there is a word-around. Use a user-action-sensitive language like JavaScript. In such case, use a data structure like associative array, where selection of an option updates the corresponding element and deselection invalidates the element in array.